# How to use a Piezo ShockSensor and an op-amp practical integrator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, piezo, integrator

I have made this circuit :

[image]

Once I apply a shock to the sensor, I get this result on the scope :

- CH1 (yellow) : piezoshock output
- CH2 (blue) : LTC6240 output

[image]

Here is the spec of the piezo sensor : 
https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/shock/healthcare/pkgs_spce_00gxp1_en.ashx?la=en-us

What we know :

1. The piezo has a 390pF capacitance (+/-) 30%.
2. The piezo gives 0.35 pC/G (0 to 50G)
3. The LTC6240 has a 3.3V+ to the Power+ and 0V to Power-

Now I am trying to understand how to calculate the gain of the integrator from the circuit above and figure out what are the G's from the mV at the output.

Comment: How did you get Trace 1?  Was the sensor connected to this circuit at the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic of a charged piezo : pC/G, mV/G, Signal analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471809/basic-of-a-charged-piezo-pc-g-mv-g-signal-analysis)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it's already my question :p But now I made the circuit and the new question is more about the calculation of the integrator

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen it's actually the sensor output. So yes, it was connected

Comment: You can drop it with an object to soft foam and get -1g  but you better bias Vin+ to prevent  the input clamp offset. Also what cable is used and length?  coax 90pf /m ?  twisted pair 60pf /m??

Comment: Did you duplicate that schematic in your circuit, including the circuit values?  You want the piezo to be biased to 3.3V / 2, and you'd really like its voltage to be close to the voltage of the op-amp's + input -- the + input is grounded then Rf is too big or you've got leakage between the pins of your amplifier.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 the cable lenght is 5mm. no twisted pair.

Comment: @TimWescott Could you share a schematic so I may try your solution ?

Comment: I need to know what you actually have before I suggest changes.

Comment: You must have some idea how to bias Vin+ in the middle of the supply range , to avoid clipping. You need to avoid 40kHz or so resonance which is all you are showing.

Comment: @TimWescott the circuit shown above is what I made. I will add the bias of 3.3V / 2 and update the question with the last modification.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I could see making an informed decision to keep the resonance effects -- possibly if I wanted to put raw data into an ADC and do the rest of the work in a DSP.  But yes, a notch filter may not be a bad idea.

Comment: Resonance effects must be reduced good structural rigidity design and mount with bees wax for dampening  or epoxy.  Due to high Q amplification and evidence of low SNR on OP’s photo , these problems limit dynamic range. Must be fixed not filtered with saturation.

Comment: You're probably right -- but I never accept "must be" until I know all the requirements.  Sorry.  I've seen knee-jerk "must be's" increase system cost unnecessarily, or even degrade the performance that actually matters, just because one design's "must be" is another one's "don't care" or "must not".  You can't judge today's designs by yesterday's requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what's going on, and what you can (maybe) do about it:

The circuit shown assumes positive and negative supply voltages on the op-amp, with the output having positive and negative excursions.  If there were no bias, you'd get exactly half the signal.

The reason you have a signal out *at all* is because there's about 1V of bias, and it just happens to be in the "right" direction.  You can't count on this.

The reason you have bias is because Rf is too big for the setup, or because you have leakage.  One giga-ohm is **BIG**.  If you had a perfectly insulating glass cylinder with wires sticking out, and you rubbed it all over with your bare fingers, you'd have a resistor with less than one giga-ohm resistance.  I suspect there's a leakage path to something, but I can't figure out what (so comments from the peanut gallery are welcome).  Looking at LTC6240 packages, and the fact that you're using a ground-referenced system suggests that, if anything, leakage paths would make the signal more *negative*, not more positive.

The reason you see activity on the bottom trace at all is because those peaks happen when the op-amp has saturated -- in normal operation the op-amp should keep it's inverting input equal to the non-inverting input.

You have not said what you can accept for a low-frequency cutoff.  You can sacrifice low-frequency performance by using a lower value of Rf (for that value of Cf, 10M-ohm would put the low-frequency cutoff at around 7Hz).  You can also sacrifice overall gain by using a larger Cf -- but you'll still have the offset that you'll need to calibrate out somehow.